# Make IIS7 Show Error? And stop showing 505 page?

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7, asp-classic

We have a classic ASP website that seems to be randomly falling over, problem is its on Win2008 / IIS7 so when by chance it happens all we can see is a 505 page?? I need to see the error on the page so I can fix it, any ideas how to make IIS7 work like IIS6 and display the errors on the page?

Answer (score 1):

Check to see if 'Send Errors To Browser' is configured properly:

1. Control Panel ->   Administrative
   Tools ->
       Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager
2. Browse to the website reporting
   errors
3. Double-Click ASP
4. Expand Debugging Properties
5. Set 'Send Errors to Browser' to True
6. Click 'Apply' at the top left of the
   IIS Manager

Answer (score 0):

Better yet, why aren't you looking at the event log for the error, or using an error reporting framework like [ELMAH](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/) to help track down issues?

Answer (score 0):

It should display the error if you can RDP (or otherwise get local) on the box and pull up the page in question.